# changing element id using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to change the third item in the list with id "musiclist" by the music genre called Alternative. I have tried the document.getElementbyID however it does not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
      function thirdItem() {
        document.getElementbyId("thirdItem").innerHTML("Alternative");}
        </script> 

    <title> Music Genres </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
    <h1> Favorite genre of music </h1>
    <p>My favorite type of music include:</p>
    <!--A list of genres of music-->
    <ol id="musiclist">
    <li id="firstItem"> Rock </li>
    <li id="SecondItem"> Hip hop</li>
    <li id="thirdItem"> Country </li>

    </ol>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a `function` it's a `property` so you need : `document.getElementbyId("thirdItem").innerHTML = "Alternative"`

Comment: You have to have some type of event that calls your function thirdItem() such as a button click. <button type="button" onclick="thirdItem()"></button>

Answer (score 3):

So you have created a method that when called will change the `innerHTML` of that element, but there are a few issues

1. You never call the method
2. function names are case sensitive so it should be `getElementById` and not `getElementbyId`
3. the `innerHTML` is a property and not a method so assign a value to it `.innerHTML = '...';`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function thirdItem() {
      document.getElementById("thirdItem").innerHTML = "Alternative";
    }
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     // this is called when the Document has been parsed and is available so you 
     // can find any element inside it
     
     thirdItem();
    });
  </script>

  <title> Music Genres </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1> Favorite genre of music </h1>
    <p>My favorite type of music include:</p>
    <!--A list of genres of music-->
    <ol id="musiclist">
      <li id="firstItem"> Rock </li>
      <li id="SecondItem"> Hip hop</li>
      <li id="thirdItem"> Country </li>

    </ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! So, there must be two script tags; one in the beginning which is the function and one where it is called at the end, before the body and html tags. If a webpage was to be added using script src, the third item changes back to Country? Is it not possible to add a webpage, as well as a function in the first script tag?

Comment: @sara no need for two `script` tags. I just wanted to show that you need to call the method and it has to happen after the DOM is ready. You could do it in the same script if it was at the bottom or you could add an event listener for when the document is ready and then call it. I will update the answer

Comment: (*also not sure what you mean with "add a webpage"*)

Answer (score 0):

1. `script` should be put at the bottom of `body`
2. you had better checkout the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) before coding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <title> Music Genres </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1> Favorite genre of music </h1>
    <p>My favorite type of music include:</p>
    <!--A list of genres of music-->
    <ol id="musiclist">
      <li id="firstItem"> Rock </li>
      <li id="SecondItem"> Hip hop</li>
      <li id="thirdItem"> Country </li>

    </ol>
  </div>
  <script>
    function thirdItem() {
      document.getElementById("thirdItem").innerHTML="Alternative";
    }
    thirdItem()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your script to the end of file or new file
2. Capitalize the B for `getElementById`
3. You can set inner html using `=`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title> Music Genres </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
    <h1> Favorite genre of music </h1>
    <p>My favorite type of music include:</p>
    <!--A list of genres of music-->
    <ol id="musiclist">
    <li id="firstItem"> Rock </li>
    <li id="SecondItem"> Hip hop</li>
    <li id="thirdItem"> Country </li>

    </ol>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
        <script>
    function thirdItem(){document.getElementById("thirdItem").innerHTML = "Alternative"}
        thirdItem();
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to change your code:

```
 function thirdItem() {
  document.getElementById("thirdItem").innerHTML = "Alternative";
}
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("thirdItem").innerHTML = "Alternative";
```

And also you need to move you script block to bottom of the file.

The reason is that, you declare function, but never call it.

Answer (score -4):

you have to add your javascript code before body ends.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<title> Music Genres </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h1> Favorite genre of music </h1>
<p>My favorite type of music include:</p>
<!--A list of genres of music-->
<ol id="musiclist">
<li id="firstItem"> Rock </li>
<li id="SecondItem"> Hip hop</li>
<li id="thirdItem"> Country </li>

</ol>
</div>
<script>
  function thirdItem() {
    document.getElementbyId("thirdItem").innerHTML = "Alternative";}
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```